# Office365 app page doesn't have __REQUESTDIGEST

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, client-object-model, jquery

My app page doesn't have `__REQUESTDIGEST` on page elements. How do I get this value from sharepoint API ? I used this codes but return `403 Forbidden error`

```
var formDigest;
    $.ajax({
        url: hostUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) {
            //$('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val(data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue)
            formDigest = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue
        },
        error: function (data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
            alert(errorMessage)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are authenticated then it is:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/contextinfo'
```

All Modern Experiences do **not** have that hidden #__REQUESTDIGEST either, so you have to call the /contextinfo endpoint

I suggest to use a `window.setInterval` function to always make sure you have a valid digest in a global variable.
Saves you from requesting a new value before every REST call and thus simplifies your code.

### From an App:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159609/how-to-get-request-digest-value-from-provider-hosted-app

Comment: First thanks for your comment. I'm authenticated. I retrieve all of lists. But when I'm trying to get digest it returns forbidden error. Do you think webAbsoluteUrl is the same Sharepoint Host url ? Like project.sharepoint.com/sites/appsite ??

Comment: Ah, are you working from an App and not straight from the Host Web? You then need to go through the request executor, I don't have that code at hand.

Comment: Yes I'm working on App. But thanks any way. I'm searching request executor now.