# Add items in Sharepoint Online modern UI list using API

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery-ajax

I need to add items into custom list which is into SharePoint Online modern UI. 
 I tried inserting the data using ajax call but it is not working in it although it is working in Classic UI. Please suggest how can we add items into Sharepoint custom list using client side scripting

Comment: So what is the code you are using?

Comment: @Ciamas : ajax call using Jquery

Comment: Still don't know anything about your code and it would simply be best to post it. From the REST perspective there is no difference between the UI's of SharePoint. What is the error you get?

Comment: Which browser you are looking into? How many items do the SharePoint list have?

Answer (score 1):

We can add the SharePoint list item using REST API's, following is the code,

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/items
method: POST
body: { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TestListItem' }, 'Title': 'Test'}
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
     X-RequestDigest: $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-type: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    content-length:length of post body
```

You can follow the link,

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-lists-and-list-items-with-rest

Comment: $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() returns null in modern UI

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the SharePoint Framework to develop and create custom code WebParts, you can (and should) use the context provided in the parent WebPart component `this.context` and send it to your Root WebPart Component (the one rendered) through its properties.

Now, your component has the context and the capabilities to use the provided SPHttpClient which does the authentication and hardwork for you : `this.props.context.spHttpClient.` with the methods `get()`, `post()` and `fetch()`.

Now if you do not use the SharePoint Framework, you find yourself in a SharePoint Page where you cannot retrieve a Request Digest anymore (and you need one to push data). You must therefore ask for one first, and use it in a `X-RequestDigest` header in your post requests.

[Office365 App Page doesn't have RequestDigest](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198569/office365-app-page-doesnt-have-requestdigest)

The method is to make a first POST to `<sitecollection>/_api/contextinfo`.

Hope this helps!